# Paypal IPN - Transaction timeout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a website using Paypal IPN to get notified when my customers paid. it works great.

Because I have limited stocks, I keep a reservation for 30 minutes. After this, a cron job set the transaction to be invalid because of timeout, and the stock is released for someone else to buy it.

The problem is, it happens that the customer don't pay in the given 30 minutes. Then I receive a notification from Paypal on my IPN script that tells me that this transaction, whom I invalidated in my database, is paid.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening ? Maybe a way to tell Paypal to cancel the order, or an immediate refund ?

Thanks ahead for any help !

Comment: if you are currently using SOAP to interact with paypal then the following api will probably be of use. https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_r_RefundTransaction

Comment: Since it is passed a year from your question, I wonder if you have found a simplest solution to this problem. Any news?

Comment: Hello, no sorry but I haven't any solution for this, I don't even work in that company anymore... Good luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find this code sample to give you a hand in completing this. https://github.com/paypal/codesamples-php/blob/master/Merchant/sample/code/RefundTransaction.php

Comment: Very nice, that could be helpfull. Still, it's a refund, I guess I can trigger it immediately from the paypal_ipn and then display the appropriate message to buyer... a cancellation would be even better than a refund, but I failed to find anything about this. I will wait a little more to see if more responses show up, and if not I will do like this. Thanks !

Comment: i don't think paypal would allow a cancellation as they wouldn't get any fee's from it however, why don't you only allocate the stock upon payment of the goods?

Comment: Well I have to keep it for the customer who first clicked "buy it". Lets say there is only 1 left, and 5 people are trying to buy it... It would be a problem